# How to create Google Site (Classic or New) using google api?

Tags: google-api, google-sites

I trying to create classic google site using api and platform developers.google.com/oauthplayground. Instead of {domainName} I use 'site', so the final URI looks like this https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/site.

```
POST https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/{domainName} HTTP/1.1
Host: sites.google.com
GData-Version: 1.4
Authorization: <your authorization header here>
```

Request Body:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:sites="http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008">
<title>Source Site</title>
<summary>A new site to hold memories</summary>
<sites:theme>slate</sites:theme>
</entry>
```

As a reult response I getting next error 'Editing of this site is disabled'.
If I change {domainName} from 'site' to something else, for example 'example.com' I get 404 Not found.